Differences between DCS and PLC systems
Since most PLC systems now have data highways or the ability to exchange data between controllers deterministically, most also provide 'easy' integration with HMI and SCADA systems with support for open protocols such as OPC etc. Distributed IO is also common among most of the major PLC vendors.
What are the main differences between PLC/SCADA systems and Distributed Control Systems (DCS)? The only things that I can think of are:

Extensive software library support for common control functions and graphics with most distributed control systems.
Dedicated lifecycle support is offered from distributed control system suppliers e.g. OEM provided maintenance, spares management, support helpdesk etc.

Are there any other key differences that I am missing?
